# Let $(\lambda_{n})$ be a complex bounded sequence, and, $T\in L(\ell^{1})$ a operator defined by $T(x)=(\lambda_{n}x_{n})$. Find spectrum $\sigma(T)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $(\lambda_{n})$ be a bounded sequence of complex numbers, and, $T:\ell^{1}\rightarrow \ell^{1}$ a operator defined by $T(x)=(\lambda_{n}x_{n})$ for $x=(x_{n})\in\ell^{1}$. Find the spactrum of $T$, that is, $\sigma(T)$.

**Remark** Note that $(T-\lambda I)$ is injective for all $\lambda\neq \lambda_{n}$ and $T(e_{n})=\lambda_{n}e_{n}$ then the point spectrum $\sigma_{p}(T)=\{\lambda_{n}\}$.

For other hand,  $T^{*}:\ell^{\infty}\rightarrow \ell^{\infty}$ is given by $T^{*}(y)=(\lambda_{n}y_{n})$  for $y=(y_{n})\in\ell^{\infty}$, then  $\sigma_{p}(T^{*})=\{\lambda_{n}\}$. Therefore,  we have
$$\lambda\in\{\overline{\lambda}_{n}\} \Longleftrightarrow \overline{\lambda}\in\{\lambda_{n}\} \Longleftrightarrow \{0\}\neq N(T^{*}-\overline{\lambda} I)=R(T-\lambda I)^{\bot}.$$
Then, we have $\overline{R(T-\lambda I)}\neq E$. Therefore, the residual spectrum is $\sigma_{r}(T)=\{\overline{\lambda}_{n}\}$. **Is this correct?**

So, we can conclude $\sigma(T)=\{\lambda_{n}\}\cup\{\overline{\lambda}_{n}\}\cup\sigma_{c}(T).$

**The problem:** I could not calculate $\sigma_{c}(T)$, I think $\sigma_{c}(T)=\overline{\{\lambda_{n}\}}$ but I do not know how to show it.

Comment: What makes you think $T - \lambda I$ is injective for all $\lambda$? We have $T(e_n) = \lambda_n \cdot e_n$, so the $\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are absolutely right, I corrected it.

Comment: Complex conjugates don't enter the picture here. We're not looking at Hilbert spaces, $T^{\ast}$ is the Banach-space-adjoint, or transpose, or dual of $T$, and the map $T \mapsto T^{\ast}$ is linear in that setting, $(T - \lambda I)^{\ast} = T^{\ast} - \lambda I$. It is easy to check that $\sigma(T) = \overline{\{ \lambda_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}}$. Do you need to identify the residual and continuous spectrum, or does the total spectrum suffice?

Comment: I needed to calculate the total spectrum, the problem I have is to show the content $\sigma(T)\subseteq\overline{\{\lambda_{n}\}}$.

Comment: If $\lambda \notin \overline{\{ \lambda_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}}$, there is a $\delta > 0$ with $\lvert \lambda - \lambda_n\rvert > \delta$ for all $n$. You can write down the inverse of $T - \lambda I$ directly then, it's the multiplication with the multiplier sequence $\mu_n = \frac{1}{\lambda_n - \lambda}$, which is bounded ($\lvert\mu_n\rvert \leqslant 1/\delta$).